# Why I am getting this error? Is their something should I have to change?

Tags: php, json, salesforce, lead

I wanted to pass my values to salesforce api. I am fetching the loan application number as you can see in last line of error. But it also showing "failed with status 200". Is their something to change in code or it just fine to have it. And I also wanted to display that Loan application number on frontend. What will be the syntax for it. I have already tried with array syntax of php but it wont work. Error is as following

```
Error: call to URL https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with status 200, response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 12:31:56 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=cLMf4KPnTvqxcif286fSRQ;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2016 12:31:56 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked "success: Loan Application Number - 804326966", curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

My code is as following

```
<?php session_start();
$json=$_SESSION['json'];
$details=json_decode($json);
//var_dump($details);
$name='LoanCreationService';
$instance_url='https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/';
$access_token = $details->{'access_token'};
$message=create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token);
//echo $message->{'message'};
function create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token) {
    $url = $instance_url;
    //$content = json_encode(array("Name" => $name));
    $content=$_SESSION['content'];;
    //echo $content;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                "Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $json_response;
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    //echo "HTTP status $status creating account<br/><br/>";

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    echo $id = $response["id"];



    return $id;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are killing it in the code, because the status you look for is 201 and the request returns 200, as you can see in the error message you return. Try to set the status to 201, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Status 200 OK, means your request in successed and you are already getting `"success: Loan Application Number - 804326966"`. See the [w3 doc](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

May be you can try with this?

```
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $json_response;
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl);

if ($output === false || $status ['http_code'] != 200) {
  $output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $status ['http_code']. "]";
  if (curl_error($curl))
    $output .= "\n". curl_error($curl);
  }
//now check the resopose

 var_dump($json_response);
    //echo "HTTP status $status creating account<br/><br/>";
    $key = "success: Loan Application Number -";
    $pos = strpos($json_response, $key);
    //echo $pos;
    $appNumber = substr($json_response,strlen($key)+ $pos,strlen($json_response));  
    echo $appNumber;
    curl_close($curl);
    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

echo $id = $response["id"];
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please tell me how to fetch only loan application number from this whole response.